# Manual filename while uploading attachments

Tags: uploads

I can't quite find what I'm looking for. I simply want to add a filename field in Add Attachment or Add Media so I can easily upload a photo from my phone to my WordPress site and then have it saved under that name I typed in instead of the phone given name like WP0023.JPG